# Pass value to a class from trigger and assign value to Object fields

Tags: apex, class

I am passing the user.info to a class from a trigger, I am able to get the correct data from the query but I am not able to insert or update the object(User) fields   with the data stored in a List (List1) where the User = userid. I am not getting any errors. Can anyone please help me, I will really appreciate it!

Trigger code:

```
trigger dashboardUser on USER (before update, before insert) {

   if (Trigger.isInsert) {
    new  dashboardUserChartLines().main(Trigger.new);
   }else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    new  dashboardUserChartLines().main(Trigger.new);
   }
}
```

Class code:

```
public class dashboardUserChartLines {

  public List<String> List1 {get;set;}
  public id userid {get;set;}

 public void main(List<User> items){
 for(User i : items){

  userid = i.id;


}
 //for mws chart
 AggregateResult[] groupedSales 
 =[SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c),  SUM(Detail_Total__c)
 FROM MWSOrderItem__c 
 WHERE  Purchase_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:365 AND Buyer_lookup__c =:userid
 GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c)
 ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c) ASC LIMIT  50000 ];

 List1 = new List<String>();  

 for (AggregateResult ar11 : groupedSales )  {

 List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr0')+'/'+String.valueof(ar11.get('expr1'))));
 List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr2')));

}

if(List1.Size()==24){

User p = new User();

p.MWS_MonthYear1__c = String.valueof(List1.get(0)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear2__c = String.valueof(List1.get(2)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear3__c = String.valueof(List1.get(4)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear4__c = String.valueof(List1.get(6)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear5__c = String.valueof(List1.get(8)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear6__c = String.valueof(List1.get(10)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear7__c = String.valueof(List1.get(12)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear8__c = String.valueof(List1.get(14)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear9__c = String.valueof(List1.get(16)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear10__c = String.valueof(List1.get(18)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear11__c = String.valueof(List1.get(20)); 
p.MWS_MonthYear12__c  = String.valueof(List1.get(22)); 

p.MWS_Month1__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(1)); 
p.MWS_Month2__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(3));   
p.MWS_Month3__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(5));
p.MWS_Month4__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(7));   
p.MWS_Month5__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(9)); 
p.MWS_Month6__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(11));   
p.MWS_Month7__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(13)); 
p.MWS_Month8__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(15));   
p.MWS_Month9__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(17)); 
p.MWS_Month10__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(19));   
p.MWS_Month11__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(21)); 
p.MWS_Month12__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(23)); 


 }

 }//end void

}
```

Comment: When creating the user instance you need to pass the Id in the constructor `User p = new User(Id = userid );` and at the end of your code `update p;`. Try that

Comment: Bachovski, i am getting an error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 00540000002P5NI) is currently in trigger dashboardUser, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []:  this is where the update p;  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues I can see with your code.

1. This line is your controller:

   userid = i.id;

On BeforeInsert events, this value will be null as an ID won't be assigned to the user records yet.

1. The query for MWSOrderItem__c records.

You're assuming that the MWSOrderItem__c records will be in place with the Buyer_lookup__c field populated with User IDs when the User trigger runs. I'm not sure how you can make this assumption, especially considering the User trigger is a before trigger. I.e. on BeforeInsert, the User records in trigger.new won't have IDs, so how will the MWSOrderItem__c records exist with this ID in Buyer_lookup__c?

Presumably you have other code to create MWSOrderItem__c records?

I would suggest moving this to an AfterInsert & AfterUpdate trigger, then consolidating the User trigger code and (presuming it exists) MWSOrderItem__c trigger code into the User trigger & helper class. Then you can perform your DML actions on both objects at once, with valid IDs in place.

Comment: This is how it works, the trigger in Object NRProduct will pass the buyer_lookup__c to the trigger in Object User then I am passing this ID to the class that you see above. this is the code for the first trigger:   Set<User> userData = new Set<User>();
 
    //Gather parents of new versions of children
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(NRProducts__c c : Trigger.new){
            if(!String.isEmpty(c.Buyer_lookup__c)){
                userData.add(new User(Id = c.Buyer_lookup__c));
            }
        }

Comment: I am getting the correct List.size() but I am not able to assign this values to User p = new User(Id = userid );

Comment: I changed it to (after update, after insert)

Comment: and it is not updating, any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in case someone is having the same issues

```
   public class dashboardUserChartLines {


public List<String> List1 {get;set;}


 public void main(List<User> items){
  for(User i : items){

  i = userid(i);

 }

}

public User userid(User p){



 AggregateResult[] groupedSales 
 =[SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c),  SUM(Detail_Total__c)
 FROM MWSOrderItem__c 
 WHERE  Purchase_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:365 AND Buyer_lookup__c =:p.id
 GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c)
 ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c) ASC LIMIT  50000 ];

List1 = new List<String>();  

 for (AggregateResult ar11 : groupedSales )  {

List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr0')+'/'+String.valueof(ar11.get('expr1'))));
List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr2')));


 }

 if(List1.Size()==24){

 p.MWS_MonthYear1__c = String.valueof(List1.get(0)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear2__c = String.valueof(List1.get(2)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear3__c = String.valueof(List1.get(4)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear4__c = String.valueof(List1.get(6)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear5__c = String.valueof(List1.get(8)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear6__c = String.valueof(List1.get(10)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear7__c = String.valueof(List1.get(12)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear8__c = String.valueof(List1.get(14)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear9__c = String.valueof(List1.get(16)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear10__c = String.valueof(List1.get(18)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear11__c = String.valueof(List1.get(20)); 
 p.MWS_MonthYear12__c  = String.valueof(List1.get(22)); 

 p.MWS_Month1__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(1)); 
 p.MWS_Month2__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(3));   
 p.MWS_Month3__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(5));
 p.MWS_Month4__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(7));   
 p.MWS_Month5__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(9)); 
 p.MWS_Month6__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(11));   
 p.MWS_Month7__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(13)); 
 p.MWS_Month8__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(15));   
 p.MWS_Month9__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(17)); 
 p.MWS_Month10__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(19));   
 p.MWS_Month11__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(21)); 
 p.MWS_Month12__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(23)); 

 }

   return p;
  }

 }
```